# Georeference a map with lambert conical orthomorphic projection

Tags: georeferencing, lambert-conformal-conic

Could you Please help me with the issue of georeferencing, I have an old map of the city of Tripoli, I want to georeference it. What type of projector should I should use?
in the image the lambert conical orthomorphic projection is used.[image]

Link of the image:

https://maps.lib.utexas.edu/maps/ams/tripolitania_city_plans/txu-oclc-6577678.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A cursory check of the EPSG site didn't turn up the projection shown on the map. You'll probably need to create a custom projection. All the information you need is there:
[image]